# How to feed this XML stream to Google maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, google-maps

I have a url that returns XML coordinates in the below format. I want to put a Google map on my page and feed it these push pin coordinates. Is there a nice and quick way to do this via Javascript or jQuery?

```
<messageList>
<totalCount>1</totalCount>
−
<message>
<esn>0-7396996</esn>
<esnName>JOHN</esnName>
<messageType>TEST</messageType>
<messageDetail> ALL IS WELL AT CURRENT LOCATION.</messageDetail>
<timestamp>2010-05-24T00:39:12.000Z</timestamp>
<timeInGMTSecond>1274661552</timeInGMTSecond>
<latitude>25.19483</latitude>
<longitude>65.7162</longitude>
</message>
</messageList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest transforming your xml into KML which google maps can handle very happily using an inbuild method called [GGeoXml](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GGeoXml).

[KML](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/) is a standard geo-coding data format which is used be a number of different mapping solutions.

or you can parse your xml and create a marker like this:

```
var point= new GLatLng(25.19483, 65.7162);
var marker = new GMarker(point);
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Comment: It should be noted that the above solution is for the V2 API. The solution changes dramatically for V3.